# Reogranizing the data frame

Tags: r

I'd like to reorganize my data frame. I just wanted to move the last column into first place and the rest leave in the same order. I used function subset to do it. It works but it would be painful if I have like 100 columns or so. 
Is there any easier way to do it ?

```
tbl_comp <- subset(tbl_comp, select=c("Description","Meve_mean","Mmor_mean", "Mtot_mean", "tot_meanMe", "tot_meanMm", "tot_sdMe", "tot_sdMm", "Wteve_mean", "Wtmor_mean", "Wttot_mean", "tot_meanwte", "tot_meanwtm", "tot_sdwte", "tot_sdwtm"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
tbl_comp <- subset(tbl_comp, select=c(Description , Meve_mean:tot_sdwtm))
```

Comment: all of them work like I wanted but this one seems to be the easiest for me because I currently used subset function.

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl_comp <- cbind(tbl_comp[ncol(tbl_comp)], tbl_comp[-ncol(tbl_comp)])
```

will do the trick.